# How to execute one script on client svn commit?

Tags: svn

I am new to SVN. I want to execute one script when client commit some code. Now i want to copy all updated code from svn server to another server so how to do so any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server, yes, see the [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html).

On client for the command-line one no, but you can create a wrapper that will take care of it. For Tortoise-SVN yes; in "Settings" there is a "Hook Scripts" tab. For other clients it depends.